# Insert into Multiple tables and carry over primary key as foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have three tables `[USER]`, `[DEMONSTRATOR]`, `[MANAGER]` The user is either a `[DEMONSTRATOR]` or a `[MANAGER]` and a manager can manage many `[DEMONSTRATOR]`s which means the primary key of the `[MANAGER]` is used as a foreign key in the `[DEMONSTRATOR]` table. With the `INSERT` statement below i want the `[MANAGER]` to be able to add a `[DEMONSTRATOR]` AND assign the primary key value of the `[MANAGER]` table as a foreign key in the `[DEMONSTRATOR]` table in the `managerID` column. How do i achieve that?

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO 
            [USER]userFirstName, userSurname, userEmailAddress, userName 
            ,userPassword,userType) VALUES(@userFirstName, @userSurname, 
            @userEmailAddress, @userName ,@userPassword,'D'); INSERT INTO 
            DEMONSTRATOR(demID, commissionPerce,status) 
            VALUES(SCOPE_IDENTITY(),'27','active');", con);
```

This SQL statement inserts a User and makes that user a Manager:

```
          SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO[USER] 
          (userFirstName, userSurname, userEmailAddress, userName, 
          userPassword, userType) VALUES(@userFirstName, 
          @userSurname, @userEmailAddress, @userName, 
          @password,'M'); INSERT INTO MANAGER(managerID,teamName) 
          VALUES(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @teamName);", con);
```

Comment: Where is the INSERT into "Manager"?

Comment: The INSERT into MANAGER is in another form and the primary key of the Manager table is an auto increment. Any Suggestions? @Ageax

Comment: View INSERT INTO MANAGER code above. @Ageax

Comment: The simplest approach would most likely be to stick these multiple `INSERT` statements into a stored procedure and just call that stored procedure from your C# code  and handle all the gory details internally, within the stored procedure.

Comment: @marc_s I how would a stored procedure make the statement different from how it is being used now because a stored procedure is also basically just SQL statements, right?

Comment: A stored procedure would allow you to assign the identity to a local variable, before inserting into the next table. This makes things a bit safer and cleaner.